# Remove records by userId not allowed

Tags: meteor

In my app an user has the option to delete all his notifications. As an event handler I have this:

```
Template.clearNotifications.events({
  'click .clear-notifications': function() {
    Notifications.remove({userId: Meteor.user()._id});
  }
});
```

When it is called, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID. [403]
```

Is this a permission I forgot to add, or is it generally not allowed to do this? And if so, what are my options to remove the user's notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client, meteor only allows the removal of documents by id. Fortunately there's an easy solution - just iterate over all of the current user's notifications and remove each one:

```js
Template.clearNotifications.events({
  'click .clear-notifications': function() {
    Notifications
      .find({userId: Meteor.userId()})
      .forEach(function(notification) {
        Notifications.remove(notification._id);
      });
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that this will only remove notifications which the client knows about (those which have been published). If there are additional notifications in the database which also need to be removed (maybe you only published the 10 most recent documents), you would need to use a [method](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods). For example:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  removeAllNotifications: function() {
    Notifications.remove({userId: this.userId});
  }
});
```

Which you can invoke from the client with:

```js
Meteor.call('removeAllNotifications');
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, this is exactly what I was looking for. And I didn't realise that removing from the client only removes the published ones!

Answer (score 0):

Removing in untrusted area (client) works only when you pass **_id** of document:

```
var notification = Notifications.findOne({userId:Meteor.userId()});
Notifications.remove({_id:notification._id})
```

Explanation:

> The behavior of remove differs depending on whether it is called by trusted or untrusted code. Trusted code includes server code and method code. Untrusted code includes client-side code such as event handlers and a browser's JavaScript console.
>
> Trusted code can use an arbitrary Mongo selector to find the documents to remove, and can remove more than one document at once by passing a selector that matches multiple documents. It bypasses any access control rules set up by allow and deny. The number of removed documents will be returned from remove if you don't pass a callback.
>
> As a safety measure, if selector is omitted (or is undefined), no documents will be removed. Set selector to {} if you really want to remove all documents from your collection.
>
> Untrusted code can only remove a single document at a time, specified by its _id. The document is removed only after checking any applicable allow and deny rules. The number of removed documents will be returned to the callback.

http://docs.meteor.com/#remove

Comment: OK, but what if I have multiple notifications, how do I iterate them?

Comment: Trusted code (server side) can do that. Create method on server side which removes notifications selected by arbitrary Mongo selector.